# how to insert data into mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I run this code and the browser reports syntax error in $sql, but I don't see any.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Recruits (name, age, college, major, college, 
        yearsOfWork, formerCompany, moreinfo) VALUES ($name, $age, $college,
        $major, $college, $yearsOfWork, $formerCompany, $moreinfo)";
```

Comment: paste your error message here.

Comment: just add single quotes when your are passing the values

Comment: Ankur's answer will do it the non parameterized way,  but you really want to use the parameterized way shown by Parker for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Recruits (name, age, college, major, college, yearsOfWork, formerCompany, moreinfo) VALUES ('$name', '$age', '$college', '$major', '$college', '$yearsOfWork', '$formerCompany', '$moreinfo')";
```

Just add single quotes on the values

Comment: Sorry it's actually some other problems but thanks all the same!

Answer (score 1):

[Please use PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), your current script is extremely vulnerable to SQL injections.

If you don't want to (which I really don't reccomend), the issue with your current code is that you're missing single quotes (`'`) around the `$` values.

Also, you put `college` twice, which will cause issues too

This is how you'd insert using PDO

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Recruits (name,
          age,
          college,
          major,
          yearsOfWork,
          formerCompany,
          moreinfo) VALUES
          :name,
          :age,
          :college, 
          :major,
          :yearsOfWork,
          :formerCompany,
          :moreinfo)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':age', $age);
$stmt->bindParam(':college', $college);
$stmt->bindParam(':major', $major);
$stmt->bindParam(':yearsOfWork', $yearsOfWork);
$stmt->bindParam(':formerCompany', $formerCompany);
$stmt->bindParam(':moreInfo', $moreInfo);

$stmt->execute();
```

This is how you'd do it using the way you're trying

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Recruits (name, age, college, major, 
            yearsOfWork, formerCompany, moreinfo) VALUES ('$name', '$age',         
            '$college', '$major', '$yearsOfWork', '$formerCompany', '$moreinfo')";
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will have to set up a database connection, remote or local.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```